# Why does using the time module with tkinter make the app lag so much when going into a new function?

Tags: python, performance, tkinter, time, lag

I'm kind of new to stackoverflow so I'm not exactly sure if I'm violating any rules right now but I imagine I'm living close to the edge. Regardless, here is my problem.
I'm trying to create a tkinter countdown timer. Everything was going smoothly and I had an app that should be working but the problem is the app begins lagging crazily once I move to a new function.

This is the code:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("453x170")

def setTimer():
    hourEntry = tk.Entry(root, width = 10)
    hourEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 20, pady = 30)

    col1 = tk.Label(root, text = ':')
    col1.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

    minuteEntry = tk.Entry(root, width =10)
    minuteEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 3, padx = 20, pady = 30)

    col2 = tk.Label(root, text = ':')
    col2.grid(row = 1, column = 4)

    secEntry = tk.Entry(root, width = 10)
    secEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 5, padx = 20, pady = 30)

    def timer():
        try:
            hours = int(hourEntry.get())
        except ValueError:
            hours = 0
        try:
            minutes = int(minuteEntry.get())
        except ValueError:
            minutes = 0
        try:
            seconds = int(secEntry.get())
        except ValueError:
            seconds = 0

        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

        totalsecs = seconds + minutes*60 + hours*60*60

        for i in range(totalsecs + 1):
            print(hours, ':', minutes, ':', seconds)

            if seconds == 0 and minutes > 0:
                minutes = minutes - 1
                seconds = 60

            elif seconds == -1 and minutes == 0 and hours > 0:
                hours = hours - 1
                seconds = 60

            seconds = seconds - 1

            result = hours, ':', minutes, ':', seconds

            for widget in root.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy()

            if seconds == 0 and minutes == 0 and hours == 0:
                time.sleep(1)
                label = tk.Label(root, text = result)
                label.grid()
                print(hours, ':', minutes, ':', seconds)
                return None

            label = tk.Label(root, text = result)
            label.grid()

            time.sleep(1)

    button = tk.Button(root, text = 'Start', command = timer)
    button.grid(row = 2, column = 3, pady = 30)


setTimer()
root.mainloop()
```

The setTimer function runs fine and allows you enter the amount of seconds minutes and hours. However, when you click the button to go to the new function, the app lags until the timer is done then it shows the result which of course is `"0:0:0"`. I suspected that constantly clearing all the widgets on the screen causes this but even after removing the `widget.destroy()` code, it lagged the same just that this time, it would end up on a screen showing every number it went through.

I spent hours removing everything one by one to check its effect on the lag but everything yielded the same lag. However, when I removed the `time.sleep(1)`, there was no lag.

Printing the results into the console doesn't lag. It only lags when the labels are on the tkinter app. All `print` statements in the code are just me showing that it doesn't lag that way.

Because of this, I'm thinking there is some sort of incompatibility between the `time` module and tkinter since another project I worked on also lagged a lot when using tkinter and time to the point where it was unusable. So I'm completely stumped.

I'm thinking it could be a case of processing power since I'm programming on a Macbook Air but I don't think the `time` module should be having such an effect.

Comment: Your code is all running in one thread. So when you call the `timer` function, nothing happens until it finishes its `for` loop.

Comment: In `tkinter` you can't do things that take a long time to run because that interferes with the running of the tkinter's own `mainloop()` and it will make everything "freeze" until they're done.

Comment: And `time` does interfere with `tkinter`.

Comment: In tkinter, you cannot use ```time``` and ```mainloop()``` in the same thread. Add the ```setTimer()``` function in another ```Thread```.

Comment: You can only access `tkinter` from one thread in a multithreaded application, so doing what @IshaanJog suggests won't work because it would break that rule.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the feedback but I don't exactly know how to make my program more multithreaded. I tried to research it but it just looked like normal code to me. Is importing thread to make a new thread recommended? Or is there a better way? Again, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do something like you want without using the `time.sleep()` function which interferes with tkinter's `mainloop()` and doesn't use separate threads which can get tricky because tkinter isn't thread-safe.

Instead it uses the universal widget method [`after()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) to schedule periodic calls to a function that counts down the time.

Note also that I've made a number of changes to your code so it follows the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines and so it's more readable and maintainable.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror, showinfo


def start_timer():
    try:
        hours = int(hourEntry.get())
    except ValueError:
        hours = 0
    try:
        minutes = int(minuteEntry.get())
    except ValueError:
        minutes = 0
    try:
        seconds = int(secEntry.get())
    except ValueError:
        seconds = 0

    totalsecs = hours*3600 +  minutes*60 + seconds

    if totalsecs == 0:
        showerror(title='Error', message=f'Please enter some amount of time.')
        return

    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    clockLabel = tk.Label(root, text=f'{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}')
    clockLabel.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

    countdown(clockLabel, totalsecs)  # Start count down process.


def countdown(clockLabel, totalsecs):

    if totalsecs == 0:
        clockLabel.bell()
        clockLabel.config(text='Finished')
        return

    hours, minutes = divmod(totalsecs, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(minutes, 60)
    clockLabel.config(text=f'{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}')

    root.after(1000, countdown, clockLabel, totalsecs-1)  # Repeat in 1000 ms.

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("453x170")

hourEntry = tk.Entry(root, width=10, justify=RIGHT)
hourEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=30)

col1 = tk.Label(root, text=':')
col1.grid(row=1, column=2)

minuteEntry = tk.Entry(root, width =10, justify=RIGHT)
minuteEntry.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=20, pady=30)

col2 = tk.Label(root, text=':')
col2.grid(row=1, column=4)

secEntry = tk.Entry(root, width=10, justify=RIGHT)
secEntry.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=20, pady=30)

startButton = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=start_timer)
startButton.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=30)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm having a hard time understanding some parts of the code because I'm not accustomed to tkinter.constant. First, what does the '02' do in the {hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}? I think I can research the rest. Once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: `tkinter.constants` are a bunch of `ALLCAPITAL` constant values primarily used to specify option values when creating widgets, such as `anchor=CENTER`. The `:02` is a format specification and means a zero-filled replacement field of width 2 — see the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) in the online documentation for details.